# Product count for anchored category in Magento2

Tags: magento2, megamenu

I am using the Megamenu third-party module in Magento 2 and I have customized this module due to some custom requirements.

I need to count product same as display in the admin category section for the anchored category and using the below code

$category->getProductCollection()->count()

this code is returning 0 products while this category is anchored and its subcategory has some product so it should count it subcategories product same as display in the admin section.

Please advise what will the code to get the products.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have successfully reindexed after setting the anchor via `php bin/magento indexer/reindex`.

Then try following code:

Include product collection factory to your construct

```
public function __construct(
        // ...
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection,
        // ...
    ) {
        // ...
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
        // ...
    }
```

And count the product collection filtered by your category.

```
$products = $this->productCollection->create();
$products->addCategoryFilter($category);
$products->count();
```